# Anyone has any idea on what is going on in this method of integration?

Tags: integration, laplace-transform, change-of-variable

Could someone show me explicitly what is going in the first line? I am confused as I have learnt Laplace transformations but I cannot figure out which Laplace transformation this is.. and the (a) in the first line, is that variable of the Laplace?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Laplace transform of a function $f(t)$ is defined as

$$\mathcal{L}\{f\}(a)=\int_0^\infty f(t)e^{-at}\,dt$$

where $a$ denotes the parameter of the integral (i.e. $a$ appears in the evaluation).

In your case, for the first line, they set $f(t)=\sin(bt)/t$.

For the second equality, the frequency domain integration property was used.

Comment: what is the frequency domain integrration ppty?

Comment: You can find a proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1054505/frequency-integration-theorem-laplace-transform) and is listed as a property [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Properties_and_theorems). Usually, to compute laplace transforms, lookup tables are used. See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Laplace_transforms#Table).